# Programmings languages that are immutable by default?

Tags: programming-languages

Are there programming languages whose "variables" are immutable (const, final, etc) by default?

And, to make it variable, you need to declare an additional immutable qualifier ?

Comment: I'm asking because I program in C/C++, and I notice I prefix almost all variables that I declare with const. So it would be nice if there are some languages out there that make everything const by default; saves my wrists and fingers. ;-)

Comment: Switch to .Net; you know you wanna.

Comment: @Hamish -- I'm _dying_ to get out of C++. Having worked on it for 5+ years, I long for increased productivity and the privilege of having useful frameworks that come _with_ the language that I found in C# and Java.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The philosophy of the [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm is strongly geared towards all "variables" being immutable, and "mutable" ones being only allowed in extreme cases (ie, for I/O).  Therefore, most functional programming languages like the various **Lisp** dialects and **Haskell** will (more often than not) reinforce immutable variables.  Of course, some languages offer more flexibility than others, but the central paradigm/philosophy remains, that discourages it.

---

Edit: In response to your edit:

If you are looking for a C-with-friendlier-constants, then adopting an entirely new programming paradigm isn't your solution.  In Functional programming, **everything** is immutable (in most cases), and you're generally looking at a whole new fundamental philosophy and approach to programming.

This *isn't* really a solution if all you want is to make it easier to declare constants.

---

Edit2: In response to people upvoting me:

While I did correctly (I hope) answer the asker's question, I'm not sure it was an answer that turned out to be useful, given his new edit/comment.  However, I can hope to possibly open his eyes to a whole new beautiful world of programming =)

---

Edit3: Here is [Wikipedia's List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_category#Functional_languages) of functional programming languages:

- APL
- Charity (purely functional)
- Clean (purely functional)
- Curl
- Curry
- Erlang
- F#
- Haskell (purely functional)

  - CAL
- Hop
- J
- Joy
- Kite
- Lisp

  - Clojure
  - Common Lisp
  - Dylan
  - Little b
  - Logo
  - Scheme
  - Tea
- Lush
- Mathematica
- Miranda
- ML

  - Standard ML
  - Alice
  - Ocaml
  - Mythryl
- Nemerle
- Opal
- OPS5
- Poplog
- R
- Q
- REFAL
- Russell
- Scala
- Spreadsheets

Most of these languages have some minor elements/influences of non-functional heresy; the ones labeled "purely functional" do not.

(To my knowledge, Functional Programming languages are the only ones that encourage immutable variables by philosophy.  There may be languages that have variables immutable, by default, that are not Functional by paradigm.  The concept sounds quite odd to me, but I can't guarantee a blanket "never ever" statement, given the vast, vast, vast number of programming languages out there.  I'll just say that it is, to my knowledge, extremely unlikely)

A commenter has suggested that **ADA** is an Imperative/Object-Oriented programming language with immutable variables by default.

Comment: @Hamish, you sure have a sense of humor. Once I checked out your SO profile, I wasn't surprised. lol.

Comment: I would weaken the comment regarding Lisp. *Some* Lisp dialects are immutable - most aren't.

Comment: Scala and Ada also require explicitly describing whether variables are mutable.

Comment: What, no mention of F#? But +1 anyway. ;)

Comment: Added a list =)  Also, clarified Lisp's loosiness as requested by Porges

Comment: Yeah, as a Common Lisp programmer, I'm not sure why it's considered a "functional language" by that WP list.  It can be *used* for FP, but so can most languages.  It's not like SML or F# or even Clojure.

Comment: I haven't programmed in Ada in 5 years, but I have no idea what the earlier comment is about.  See examples of declaring Ada variables (and constants) here: http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~csci51/fall99/ada_note.html#variable_types

Comment: and Elixir, which is built on Erlang

Comment: I think Rust is in that odd place of not quite being functional but having immutable variables. https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2018/10/is-rust-functional

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Haskell and Erlang are two examples.

Answer (score 6):

Clojure is a Lisp dialect targeting the Java Virtual Machine working exclusively with immutable data.

http://www.clojure.org

Comment: -1 Clojure's philosophy is IMO to maximize immutable data, but use mutable reference when necessary. The problem with data mutation is that of safety and concurrency, but Clojure has STM that makes mutation of references safe.

Comment: @ewerli> I think you misunderstood the concept of immutability in Clojure. Rich Hickey, the author of Clojure, explains in depth the concepts underlying the immutability in this keynote: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey

Comment: @HamishGrubijan But Clojure is a Lisp dialect, and F# is based on ML. None of the two kicks the other one's ass.

Answer (score 6):

The closest analog I can think of is [Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/).  Variables bound by `let` are always immutable, but the fields of structures (called records in Caml) are immutable only by default, and it is possible to tag an individual field as `mutable`.

Among functional languages, Objective Caml has proven remarkably attractive to C programmers.  OCaml has quite a few imperative constructs in both the language and libraries, so the migration path is not so strange.  And if you really want objects and a class system, they are there too.

Microsoft's .NET language F# is a descendant of Objective Caml, but there have been quite a few changes to make sure it is a .NET language, and I am not informed about mutability.
But if you are wanting to try out a functional language as a relatively small change from your current programming style, you might wish to investigate Objective Caml or F#.

Answer (score 5):

Rust might be something you'd want to take a look at. Its an imperative-style language that adhere's to functional programming philosophy [surprisingly often](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2018/10/is-rust-functional).

Answer (score 4):

All variables in XSLT may only be immutable.